# Database Sync between two Local DBs using MS Sync Framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, localdb

I am interested in knowing if there is any way to sync two local db database across different computers using Sync Framework? If not then what are alternatives?

Comment: you might want to mention what type of database...SQL Ce, SQLite, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: SQL Express Localdb

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework should be able to sync LocalDb databases across networks. You use the same SqlSyncProvider for it.